# Помогите настроить HTTP/2 на сервере Apache

Tags: apache2, apache2.4, http2

Версия Apache: 2.4.23

В конфигурацию файла http.conf добавил строчку:

```
LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
```

(Модуль естественно лежит в нужной папке)

Конфигурация httpd-vhosts.conf  :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/apache/test7.ru/www"
ServerName test7.ru
Protocols h2c http/1.1
ServerAlias www.test7.ru
ErrorLog "C:/apache/test7.ru/error.log"
CustomLog "C:/apache/test7.ru/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Далее захожу в файл access.log и вижу что остался HTTP/1.1
Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C **HTTP/2** проблема на самом деле двусторонняя.

С одной стороны участвует веб-сервер, с другой - клиент (например, браузер). Логично.

Основная проблема заключается в том, что мало настроить http2 на веб-сервере, также необходимо чтобы клиент (браузер) захотел/умел этим воспользоваться.

К сожалению, на текущий момент (февраль 2018) интернеты содержат много всяких объяснений, как это сделать, но эти объяснения порой взаимоисключающие.

Например, некоторые пишут, что http2 можно юзать на 80-м порту прописав простую директиву `Protocols h2c http/1.1` и все у вас заработает. Лично я не смог добиться протокола http2 на 80-м порту от актуальных современных браузеров. Возможно плохо пытался.

С другой стороны, собственно, браузеры.

Утверждается, опять таки в интернетах, что все современные браузеры поддерживают работу протокола http2, но только на соединениях TLS 1.0 и выше, и обязательно с современными шифрами. Это означает, что имея на веб-сервере, например, только SSL 3.0, вы не получите никакого http2 от браузера. И в этом случае уже браузер будет решать, будет ли он использовать http2.

Если вернуться к вашему вопросу, то могу предложить свою конфигурацию, которая работает по http2.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

    SSLCertificateFile          /etc/apache2/sites-available/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile       /etc/apache2/sites-available/cert.key

    ServerName web-server
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

В логах Апача при этом:

```
"GET /index.html HTTP/2.0" 200 3186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
```